# How to let hibernate auto-generate a database EnumType?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

My goal is to create an `@Entity` that auto-generates the following table with hibernate:

```
CREATE TABLE data_history (
    id bigint auto_increment,
    action enum('INSERT','UPDATE','DELETE'),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Problem is the enum: how can I tell hibernate to generate that enum type?

I tried as follows:

```
@Entity
public class DataHistory {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long id;
    
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public DatabaseTrigger action;
}

public enum DatabaseTrigger {
    INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
}
```

Result:

```
action varchar(255) NOT NULL
```

Comment: Hibernate only support by default String and int types, if you would like to custom it by your own enum you should follow this article: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-an-enum-type-with-jpa-and-hibernate/, `Mapping a Java Enum to a database-specific Enumerated column type` part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not yet possible. Maybe in 6.x we will introduce support for this, but right now, you would have to do this manually.